# Problem with gradle build flavour and packagingOptions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been developing for a while a library (in aar format) that is compatible with x86, armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a abis. The library works as expected but, in order to reduce the final size, we want to develop two different libraries: one with arm64-v8a abi and one without it. The library depends on openCV (used in C++ language) and we have the following project structure:

```
src
 |_ main
     |_ jniLibs
           |    | arm64-v8a
           |----| armeabi-v7a
                | x86
```

Each abi folder contains libopencv_java3.so.

I have created two product flavours, each one with the abiFilters needed to work properly.

```
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    v7a {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }
    }
    v8a {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have two build variants to select and both compile without errors. However, the v7a aar still contains the arm64-v8a folder and library inside it. To solve this, I have added to v7a flavour the following:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so'
}
```

Now, v7a aar does not contain the arm64-v8a folder inside it but when I select v8a flavour, the folder exists but no libopencv_java3.so is placed inside it!

Should not this option only affect to v7a? What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Notes: gradle version tested: 3.1.2 and 3.1.4.

Answer (score 2):

try to split differently, instead of using product favors -

alike this one can load `armeabi-v7a` assembly on `arm64-v8a`:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi", "x86"
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

this would expect the (32bit version of the) library at `armeabi/libopencv_java3.so`.

`externalNativeBuild` only considers the libraries, which are being built (aka "your code"). if you insist on using the `packagingOptions`, you should not define them globally, but per product flavor.

```
v7a {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try the splits when I have access to the code. Regarding to the packagingOptions, that is what I did (putting it only inside v7a) but it keeps removing the OpenCV library when building for v8a!!

Comment: @MiguelIsla loading the same library for both architectures would at least not bloat the package unnecessarily. meanwhile there also is https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/ which would also support, what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, I will have a look at it. I have one more question regarding using armeabi. This abi is deprecated and no longer supported, so in the near future, this solution would not work. Any idea of a possible workaround for this?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue where I try to exclude one native library from a build flavor, but when adding the packagingOption to exclude per flavor, the library is not available for any flavor! So looks like packagingOptions is applied globally to all flavors which is not what I expected.